# nodejs - javascript [xmldom warning] unclosed xml attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmldom

In nodejs i am reading a xml file and converting into xml object so that i can process it further. Things are fine and working but i am getting a warning continuously when i execute in windows cmd

```
D:\Work\public>node xml-js.js
[xmldom warning]        unclosed xml attribute
@#[line:370,col:7]
object
```

My xml-js.js code is as below,

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var fs = require('fs');
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var xpath = require('xpath');
var fsxml = fs.readFileSync('SMALL1.xml', 'utf8'); 
var filedata = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fsxml);
console.log(typeof filedata)
................
...............
other code.
```

Please let me know why i am facing this error and how to get rid of it.

thanks

Comment: I believe `xml-js` is simply complaining about unclosed attributes/tags in the ingested XML file(s) -- not your code specifically

Comment: Thanks @arthurakay. you are right. the problem was with my xml.